# How to upgrade OroCommerce 3.1 to 4.1

Tags: upgrade, orocommerce

I'm upgrading an OroCommerce installation from version 3.1.17 to 4.1.1.

I've upgraded php to 7.3.15 and I'm going through the upgrade instructions in a VM.

When I run the command `sudo php bin/console oro:platform:update --env=prod --force` I get this message:

```
In OroEntityExtendBundle.php line 121:

  In ContainerBuilder.php line 1032:                     

    You have requested a non-existent service "mail".
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the [changelog.md](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/d9292b4419451e709016e6bf8aaa485808f4e0ee/CHANGELOG.md) to see all the changes that the customization can be affected with.

Here is the related paragraph:

> Due to the updated version of `symfony/swiftmailer-bundle` parameter
>   `mailer_transport: mail` is not supported anymore. Using old transport
>   will cause such an exception
>
> `Unable to replace alias
>      “swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport.real” with actual definition
>      “mail”. You have requested a non-existent service “mail”.`
>
> Please use
>   `mailer_transport: sendmail` instead or another available swiftmailer
>   transport type.

https://github.com/oroinc/platform/search?l=Markdown&q=mail%20sendmail

Answer (score 0):

I just found my answer at https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

The problem was I copied the parameters from my previous installation and the mail transport is not up to date.